# how to monitor the impact of a newly added feature in a website-ecommerce?

Tags: analytics, analysis, clickstream, bigdata

I am not sure if I am using the right tags for my question so feel free to moderate and change it to more relevant ones.
I recently implemented a recommendation widget and now I am ready to integrate it with an existing ecommerce shop. I want to be able to closely monitor how users deal with my recommended items , what they click and how those recommendations impact the overall revenue. In other words I want to see the impact of my new feature on the ecommerce. What are the best tools/methods of doing this?Are there any implemented examples? Is this a kind of big data thing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid this is probably too broad and webmaster-y for Stack Overflow. I can't promise the question will work there, but it may be worth taking a look at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com and seeing whether it might

Comment: Most analytics suites (like Google Analytics or Piwik, which is self-hosted, Open Source and great) bring features for measuring this kind of thing. See e.g. http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-campaigns/

Comment: Thank @Pekka웃 for your quick response. I will give it a try ! Hopefully my question will be answered :-)